# Does facebook have a logout page?

Tags: facebook, authentication, logout

I'm doing a basic image sharing where people will have to connect to facebook/twitter => share => logout.

I don't need to use either SDKs so the user are logging in before they share, I want the logout to be as simple as possible, even if it's in a popup.

Twitter as a nice https://twitter.com/logout where you confirm if you want to logout.
I can't find anything like this for facebook, does a similar page exist for facebook ?

Thanks.

Comment: I've seen it using the website: https://Facebook.com/logout.php

Comment: I tried some stuff with it (POSTing to it, testing the mobile version) but nothing work. I don't want to logout people, because I doubt it's feasible, I just want a logout page where people can just click a button to log out.

Comment: I don't think Facebook has one as the logout is just a click of a button and a redirect to the front page. Maybe this API will help: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/logout.php` is the correct URL to log users out automatically, but you need to pass a valid user access token as parameter (name `access_token`) and a `redirect_uri` (URL of the page of your site where they are taken back to after logout).

Comment: I know but like I said, I'm not login the users so I don't have those params.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any logout page separately